# The transaction declared chain ID 4, but the connected node is on 1

Tags: python, cryptography, blockchain, solidity, web3py

I am using Rinkeby and its chainId is 4 but I get this error below:
web3.exceptions.ValidationError: The transaction declared chain ID 4, but the connected node is on 1

I checked every list and rinkeby chain Id was 4 but I get this error.

I checked everything but I failed every time. This is my code:
(NOTE: I remove my address and PK for security)

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import json
from web3 import Web3

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

print("Installing...")
install_solc("0.6.0")

# compile our solidity
install_solc("0.6.0")

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)


# get bytecode
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]["object"]

# get abi
abi = json.loads(
    compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["metadata"]
)["output"]["abi"]


# for connecting to rinkeby
w3 = Web3(
    Web3.HTTPProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/d2cd31c721a94005852679fb57b5c068")
)
chain_id = 4
my_address = #
private_key = #

# Create the contract in python
SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)


# get the latest transaction
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)


# 1. build a transaction
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
)

# 2. sign the transaction
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
print("Deploying Contract!")

# 3. send transaction
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
# working with contract, you always need
# contract address
simple_storage = w3.eth.contract(address=tx_receipt.contractAddress, abi=abi)

# initial value of favorite number
print(simple_storage.functions.retrieve().call())
print("UPDATING ...")
store_transaction = simple_storage.functions.store(15).buildTransaction(
    {
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce + 1,
    }
)
signed_store_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
    store_transaction, private_key=private_key
)
send_store_tx = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_store_txn.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(send_store_tx)
print(simple_storage.functions.retrieve().call())
print("UPDATED!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your provider endpoint:

```
Web3.HTTPProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/d2cd31c721a94005852679fb57b5c068")
```

You are connected to mainnet node. You should get the endpoint for rinkeby.

From settings of your project, get rinkeby node:

[image]